# Erro de responsividade no HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

Quando minimizo a tela, as fotos ficam fora do bloco, segue o código HTML e CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="PT-BR">
<head>
    <title>Cartola dos Amigos</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Pacifico|Roboto+Slab:400,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>
<body>

        <nav>
            <a href="#">DICAS DO CARTOLA</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#inicio">INÍCIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#times">TIMES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  

            <section id="inicio">
            <h2>INÍCIO</h2>
            <p>Somos uma liga que começou com uma brincadeira de quem é realmente apaixonado por futebol e veio crescendo com o passar do tempo</p>
            <img src="image/9.jpg" alt:"9">
            </section>


            <section id="times">
            <h2>TIMES</h2>
            <p> Temos para você os mais variados times que você pode apostar e escolher para sua mitada ou ganho ainda mais de cartolas.</p>
            <div>
           <div class="figure">
               <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
                   <p>Time do Editor</p>
                   <figcaption><p>ESCALAÇÃO</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
               </div>

               <div class="figure">
                   <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
                    <p>Time do Editor</p>
                   <figcaption><p>ESCALAÇÃO</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>

               </div>

               <div class="figure">
                   <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
                   <p>Time do Editor</p>
                   <figcaption><p>ESCALAÇÃO</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>

               </div>

                <div class="figure">
                    <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
                    <p>Time do Editor</p>
                    <figcaption><p>ESCALAÇÃO</p></figcaption>
                    <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
               </div>                       

               <div class="figure">
                   <p><img class=scaled src="image/3.jpg" alt="cartola"></p>
                   <p>Time do Editor</p>
                   <figcaption><p>ESCALAÇÃO</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
                   <figcaption><p>Goleiro: Wilson R$ 10,00</p></figcaption>
               </div>   
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="contato">
            <h2>CONTATO</h2>
            <p>Entre em contato agora mesmo conosco</p>
            <a href="tel:xx55555555">(xx)0000-0000</a>


        <a href="mailto:email@contato.com.br">email@contato.com.br</a>
     </section>

     <footer>
         <p> Desenvolvido por Saxum Tecnologia</p>
     </footer>

</body>
</html> 

/*
GERAL
*/

body{
    font-family:"Open Sans", Helvetica,Arial sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}
h1,h2,h3{
    margin:0%;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", Helvetica,Arial sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;

}
/*
Menu botões configuração
*/
.botao{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
/*
NAVEGAÇÃO
*/

nav {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #000000;

}
nav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Pacifico,serif;

}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;

}

nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f1f1f1;

}

/*
CABEÇALHO
*/

header {

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

header p {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

/*
SOBRE
*/

#inicio {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;,
    background-image: url('../image/9.jpg');
    background-size: contain;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  20px 20px;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

#sobre .botao {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}

#times{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: #000000;

}

div {
  display:flex;
  text-align: top; 
  bottom: auto;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;


}

div.figure {

  display: table;
  padding:  10px 10px;
  min-width: 30px;  


}

div.figure p + p {
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-style:oblique;
  background: #000000;
  color: #A9A9A9



}

figcaption p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color:#000000;
  color:#f1f1f1


}





/*
CONTATO
*/

#contato{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

/*
FOOTER
*/

footer{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/*
MEDIA QUERIES
*/

@media screen and (min-width:300px){
    /*
    MEDIA QUERIES
    */
    nav{
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    nav ul{
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 70%;
    }
    /*
   CABEÇALHO 
    */

    header{
        height: 600px;
        height: 60vh;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    /*
    SOBRE
    */

    #sobre{
        height: 250px;
        height: 30vh;
        justify-content: center;
        min-height: 250px;
    }

    /*
    SERVIÇOS
    */

    #inico {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
        max-width: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-image: url('../image/9.jpg');

    }

    /*
    PORTFOLIO
    */

    #times {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    div{
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: auto;

    }

    #times h2 {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;

    }

    #times p{
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    }

    div.figure {

        float: left;
        width: -100%;
        padding: 0px;


    }


    #contato{
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
    #contato h2,
    #contato p{
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: As respostas resolveram, ajudaram? Tem algum problema que possa ser melhorado? Se atendeu ao problema, marque ️✔️ na resposta para que a pergunta não fique pendente de resolução. ObG!

Answer (score 1):

As imagens não possuem um `width` responsivo. Na verdade não há nenhum `width` nas imagens, assim elas não irão acompanhar a largura da `div` onde estão inseridas e ficarão com tamanho fixo.

Adicione no seu CSS:

```
.scaled{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Que é a classe das imagens. Assim elas irão acompanhar a largura da `div`.

Se quiser que elas tenham uma largura mínima ou máxima:

```
.scaled{
   width: 100%;
   min-width: LARGURA_MÍNIMApx;
   max-width: LARGURA_MÁXIMApx;
}
```

Substituindo `LARGURA_MÍNIMA` e `LARGURA_MÁXIMA` pelo valor que deseja.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui!!!

Comment: Já sabe o que tem que fazer quando a sua pergunta foi resolvida?

Answer (score 0):

Também pode utilizar um `img{max-width:100%}` em seu css.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui com o comentário acima